# Matplotlib: how to increase the area saved without increasing the figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently the area of the figure that gets saved by  is fixed, so if I have the legend outside the figure, it gets cropped off, like that:

[image]

Is there a function in matplotlib that allows to save larger area than the standard area of the figure, so I can save my figure with the legend, like below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bbox_inches='tight'` should do the trick:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

> `bbox_inches`:
>
> Bbox in inches. Only the given portion of the figure is
>       saved. If 'tight', try to figure out the tight bbox of
>       the figure.

#### Example

```
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.legend(['abc'], loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 0.9))
```

results in this png:

[image]